# Is it secure to allow users add raw HTML text to QTextEdit?

Tags: html, qt

I have an application which has embedded small chat window to which users can post. I am adding the text as html using this function: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#html-prop because I am using some color formatting, but I figured out that if users are using html tags, like `<b>` they are working too (which makes sense).

I can of course encode these, but I was testing it for vulnerabilities and I just can't find any. When I create a link it's not clickable and images and similar elements just display some icon instead. Can I safely keep this option or is there any potential risk in letting users add html code in the chat? I don't know if this `QTextEdit` is able to handle all html or just some basic text formatting tags in which case, it would be just fine.

Edit: here is a list of supported tags http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html I am however no expert to decide if some of these can be somehow dangerous

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it is safe (because there are a lot of [forbidden attributes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html#block-attributes) (i.e. they supported very small subset of HTML), many smart people thought about security problems and so on), but practically it is near impossible to implement so complex system without security problems.

So, it is not too dangerous to allow user's HTML for visualization in chat window. But it sounds like very bad idea to allow user's HTML in critical application (in aviation and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Given that I wasn't able to figure out whether all of these tags could be safe I created this simple function that will encode all entities except for safe tags that can be specified by user:

```
QString SafeHtml(QString text)
{
    QString result;
    QStringList AllowedTags;
    AllowedTags << "b" << "big" << "font" << "i" << "u";
    // we split the text by starting element
    QStringList Part = text.split('<');
    bool FirstPart = true;
    foreach (QString part, Part)
    {
        // split removes the symbol we use to split by so we need to return it back there
        if (FirstPart)
            FirstPart = false;
        else
            part = "<" + part;
        // if there is no closing we don't want to render this tag
        if (!part.contains(">"))
        {
            result += part.toHtmlEscaped();
            continue;
        }
        // now we need to find what tag it is
        QString tag = part.mid(1, part.indexOf(">") - 1);
        if (tag.startsWith("/"))
            tag = tag.mid(1);
        if (tag.contains(" "))
        {
            // this is some composite tag
            tag = tag.mid(0, tag.indexOf(" "));
        }
        if (!AllowedTags.contains(tag))
            part = part.toHtmlEscaped();
        result += part;
    }

    return result;
}
```

it doesn't handle unclosed html tags though, so if someone add just `<b>` it may turn all remaining text as bold etc.

Answer (score -1):

As long as you handle any bad data in the server side, you should be ok with this. The issue is when things make it to the server and how the server will process it. You have to be setup to handle code injections, sql injections, and cross domain attacks. Make sure you have error checking for malicious scripts. Other then that, a lot of different cms system use editors like this.

Comment: This question is not about web-servers and CMS. This question is about Qt and using of HTML for setting style of text/background/... on widgets.

Comment: that wasn't specified in the original question.